# Does $f(x)=o(x^n) \forall n$ imply $f^{(n)}(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^\infty$ and $f(x)=o(x^n)$ when $x\to 0$, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it true that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What's $k$?​​​​

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is no. To the one in the body of the text is yes if k=infinity. If k is not infinity, again the answer is no.

Comment: I've edited, thanks.

Comment: The answer is yes because of uniqueness of the coefficients in Taylor's formula.

Comment: I don't see why you can replace $f^{(n)}(x)/x$ with $f(x)/x^{n+1}$ under the limit. L'Hopital's rule does not work backwards.

Comment: @127.0.9.6: I've used $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)/x}{x}$ and induction, but I think it's wrong...

Comment: I don't know how you justify "$\frac{f'(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)/x}{x}$". The existence of limit on the right does not imply the existence of limit on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the Taylor formula with the [Peano form of the remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem): 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k + o(x^n)
$$