# Infinite differentiability at zero of function with property $f(x)=o(x^n)$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_+$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Is it true that the differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=o(x^n)$ for every positive $n$ is infinitely differentiable at $0$?

Given the differentiability constraint, it seems to rule out all the pathological examples I'm aware of, yet, I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Little o notation only means that $f$ is *eventually* dominated by $x^n$. We can still have that $f$ is erratic at $0$ as long as $f$ eventually becomes bounded.

Comment: @Bryan I understood that $o(x^n)$ refers to $x\to 0$; but the OP should have been more clear at this point.

Comment: Ok thanks. That would be a more interesting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A counterexample: $$f(x)=e^{-1/x^2} \sin( e^{1/x^2})$$ extended by $f(0)=0$. It is once differentiable everywhere, including $0$. It has the required decay at $0$. But
$$f'(x) = \frac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}\sin(e^{1/x^2}) - \frac{2}{x^3}\cos (e^{1/x^2})$$ is not differentiable, or even continuous, at $0$.

---

Perhaps related: [Does $f(x)=o(x^n) \forall n$ imply $f^{(n)}(0)=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/711397/127096)